# Merge PDF files

Tags: pdf

I already read the thread how to merge epub files but Is there any way by which I can merge different pdf files into one. Earlier I have tried an app for this purpose but I lost all my pdf files after merging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For serious work with PDF, you can't stay away from Adobe Acrobat… still…

You might also look at Nitro.

Comment: If Acrobat's price is a bit steep, Foxit's PhantomPDF offers similar functionality for a more reasonable price. I used it extensively at a previous job and highly recommend it.

Answer (score 4):

After a long search, I have downloaded PDFmate to merge pdf files. It works nice. It is free as well as from a verified publisher.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pdftk`:

```
pdftk file1.pdf file2.pdf cat output combined.pdf
```

Comment: I downloaded pdftk but it shows that its source is unknown and it is no safe to run programs from unknown sources as it can harm your computer.

Comment: @Vibhu I just installed it with `apt-get install pdftk` on my Linux machine. You should install a VM if you are running Windows (or abandon Windows completely if your security concerns are serious).

Answer (score 2):

You can use

- [PDFsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/), free and open source desktop application.
- [sejda.com](https://sejda.com/), free web application application

Sejda also offers a command line version, free and open source.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of all of them.

Comment: Will it show the same thing - source is unknown , when I run it?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question, can you clarify?

Comment: After downloading PDFsam, when I run it, will the computer show that its source is unknown and it is not safe to run programs from unknown source? Or will it have any verified digital signature?

Comment: The [MSI installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsam/files/pdfsam/2.2.4/pdfsam-v2_2_4.msi/download) is signed

Answer (score 1):

If you use OS X then the included Preview.app allows merging.

Open up one pdf file and then choose via the menus Edit->Insert->Page From File...

This prompts for a file - choose the second pdf and it adds all the pages from it to the original.

Comment: I use Window 7 (professinal).

Answer (score 1):

Kvisoft PDF Merger , available only for 30 day trial. Pdf combine also works.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to use [PDFsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/), which also happens to be *OpenSource* (in its Basic installment). [Here's a guide](http://www.ryadel.com/en/scan-both-sides-of-a-front-back-document-in-a-single-pdf-with-pdfsam/) explaining what it can do, with a strong focus on the *Alternate Mix* feature which is one of its major strenghts.

Answer (score 0):

A shameless plug for other who may have this problem in the future:

I built a [web tool to merge PDFs](https://typst.app/tools/merge-pdf/) for when I needed to bundle up some files. It's free to use and does not upload your documents to a server, so they stay private.