# How to remove and add certain pages from pdf file?

Tags: pdf, editing

There are PDF files which are very long and most of the pages don't provide any essential information. So I want to keep only those pages which are relevant and want to get rid of unnecessary material. I have found threads which provide information on how to edit an epub file but not pdf.

Most of you might feel that solution of this question is same as for "Merge PDF File". They are different in following aspects:

1. Merging and deletion are different and here I am asking for deletion not merging. If someone likes to give same solution then their answers are duplicate not my question.
2. The answers given for merging of PDF files doesn't provide solution how to add pages at specific location in a PDF file.
3. It also doesn't specify how to remove just few pages from a single PDF. Solutions given to "MERGE PDF FILES" just implies how to merge two PDF files using range specification method , in order to omit particular pages.

Comment: This question gets the same answer as for http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/5806/merge-pdf-files/

Comment: @MaxWyss - I don't think that this question can have same answer as the link provided by you in your comment.

Comment: I stand to my answer given for the other question. The applications suggested there are multi-purpose applications which can both things you asked for. Of course, if you are looking for single-purpose applications, then state so!

Comment: @ Max Wyss - Thank you, for giving answer to my questions. I appreciate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is an online tool konwerter, which can be used to delete the selected pages you don't need from the PDF.

Comment: Of course online tools are never to be used for copyrighted material. It would not be the first time that something got inadvertently public by someone inexperienced using an online service to get some task done that could be done locally.

Comment: It is not mentioned that the pdf is copyrighted , so how can be you so sure? If you want to do things in your way that doesn't mean that every should do it in the same way. By the way everyone can google it. It can't be either your way or no way.

Comment: I am not sure that the OP talks about copyrighted material, but it is a possibility. What I am sure about is that you didn't warn for the dangers of the exploitable online services. That might be out of ignorance, but potential users of such a service should, IMO,  be actively warned about the negative side-effects using such a service might have.

Comment: In merge pdf files, you haven't mentioned the risks of running a software from an unverified publisher. You are more busy in finding faults in other people's opinion. If you have even tried, to really understand my answer you would have known that the online tool in my answer use a secure protocol.

Comment: @Megan A secure protocol doesn't help you at all if you can't trust the other side not to divulge your information that you upload. Caution is appropriate if you don't know who operates the site. The free `pdftk` needed for the merging or deleting pages  is open source, you can check the [source code](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-version-history/) it if you don't trust it before compiling.

Comment: @Holger What about the people who don't know how a source code works? And then why banks use these protocols for transaction?I am not against someone's idea, it is good people give their opinion but they should know how to present it.

Comment: Source code can be reviewed by someone else for you if you don't trust something. If it ships with e.g. OSX or Linux you can be sure it was vetted by multiple people. Just like the "secure" protocols have been looked at by others (or did you review SSL/TLS yourself?). So I hope you don't sent your credit card information just *anywhere* because you trust the protocol to be secure, above anything else you have to trust the final recipient. o-o

Answer (score 3):

I think that PDFtk is the tool you need.

https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

Answer (score 2):

Try using Adobe Acrobat. That programme has lots of functions like: toggling pages and removing pages!

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try to CutePDF, if you use windows.
For more information , you can use the following link,

http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Pages-from-a-PDF-File

Answer (score 0):

Under any Mac OS after 10.7, the included *Preview* PDF reader tool will allow you to do any of those manipulations with great ease. Just display the thumbnails of the file and you can delete or drag any page of a PDF file. You can even add any page from any other PDF file with this method. As simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools that can do what you need - which is both add an additional page and delete a page. You can find these tools at [DeftPDF](https://deftpdf.com)

1. Delete PDF page tool - can delete specific pages by entering page numbers on the text box or simply clicking the page to delete. Can delete multiple pages at one click.
2. Edit PDF tool - can delete one by one and insert pages one by one as you scroll through the PDF.
3. Extract PDF pages - Can pick out the pages you only need so you don't have to delete but it will keep only those you want. Somehow it's similar to deleting or removing unwanted pages.
4. Split PDF tool - If pages you need are at a certain range and the others are just unwanted pages, just split them up to that page.
5. Combine and reorder - Can also both delete and insert pages. You can also reorder the existing pages to the order that you need so the pages will be inserted to where you need it to be.

[source](https://deftpdf.com/blog/5-tools-that-allow-you-to-delete-pdf-pages-from-deftpdf)

Answer (score 0):

it is very easy to do so using any pdf editor like wondershare or Masterpdf editor and many others. I edit books using masterpdf editor and i am sure you can find a free alternative